# Using fancytooltips in Sharelatex

Tags: sharelatex, fancytooltips

I'm using Sharelatex and I'd like to use fancytooltips. I'm not an advanced user. I followed some examples and uploaded a fancytoolstips.sty and a eforms.sty that I found googleing. I have no errors but the pop up with the text is not working on mouse over in the pdf generated (I tried in the Adobe Reader, not only in the Sharelatex preview). Could someone guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I asked the Sharelatex team. And they answered that **fancytooltips "*It is not currently supported by ShareLaTeX.*** I will add it to our list of feature requests and hopefully it will be available in the future."